# What Java Key:Value Data Type To Use For Duplicate Values?

Tags: java

Please forgive this rather basic question, but I'm very new to Java and still finding my way.

I'm writing a web scraper and need to store key:value data in some way. I've used HashMaps until now which have been great, except that now I need to allow duplicate values for unique keys. For example, this should be allowed:

```
Key:Value
abc : 123
cde : 727
efg : 123
hij : 123
klo : 876
opa : 909
```

Can anyone advise what would be best to use in these circumstances?

Thanks

Comment: `HashMap` should work just fine for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already possible using `java.util.HashMap`. It's duplicate *Keys* that are not possible.

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

From [java.util.Map<sup>JavaDoc</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (implemented by HashMap).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It turns out that the reason I thought they couldn't was because of a bug elsewhere in my code. I suspected that values couldn't be duplicated and further research turned up some (mis)information that confirmed my suspicion, I should have researched more carefully. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map (HashMap is OK) with a List.

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

void put(String key, String value)
{
  List<String> entry = map.get(key);
  if(entry == null)
  {
    entry = new ArrayList<String>();
    map.put(key, entry);
  }
  entry.add(value);
}

List<String> get(String key)
{
  return map.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a map from keys to some sort of collection. There's nothing built into Java for this (although there are multi-map types in other collection frameworks like [Apache Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) and [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)). If you just want to keep track of what values are associated with each key, with no order or count info, you could use

```
Map<KeyType, Set<ValueType>> map = new HashMap<KeyType, Set<ValueType>>();
```

Unfortunately, insertion is a bit more complex. You need to test whether the key exists and, if not, first add a `Set<ValueType>` under the key. Then you can add the new value to the set.